# Why does jslint complain Unexpected '`' on template strings

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jslint

I am using JSLint with syntastic in Vim and when I have a simple `.js` file like so

```
var a = 99;
var b = `I am ${a} years old`;
```

Why does Syntastic (and thus jslint) give me this error

```
Unexpected '`'
```

Comment: Because you don't have Syntastic configured property to recognize valid (modern) syntax.

Comment: Because json data should not have '`' character

Comment: JSON or JavaScript?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/quotes

Comment: @Phix Fixed it (it's js)

Comment: What editor are you using? Where do you see the jslint error?

Comment: @ruffin I am using vim with syntastic plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think you're asking a trick question. With the most recent version of JSLint, your code lints fine.

Try it out on [jslint.com](http://jslint.com).

It used to be that [JSLint didn't support es6 (ES2015) features out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36104136/jslint-edition-latest-unexpected-es6-feature-const/36265255#36265255), and you had to explicitly tell it you were using es6.

Template literals (`) weren't a thing until ES2015 (again, aka es6), which [leaves out many browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#browser_compatibility). And older copies of JSLint assumed you were serving up your JavaScript as written to browsers that might only be es5 compliant unless you told it you're in ES2015 (es6) mode.

So try putting `/*jslint es6 */` at the top of your file and see if it lints.

But more importantly: Update your version of JSLint.