# can anyone help me with this error i got in my script while makinga a hamburger menu on a websit

Tags: javascript, eslint, jslint

code:

```
let bar = document.querySelector('.bars'),
navItem = document.querySelector('.nav-items');
bar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    navItem.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

issue:

```
JsLint:
expected an indentifier and instead saw 'let'. let bar = document.querySelector('.bars'),


ESLint:

ERROR: Parsing error; Unexpected token bar let bar = document.querySelector('.bars'),

ERROR: Parsing error; Unexpected token ) let bar = document.querySelector('.bars'),
```

so the hamburger menu displays correctly

Comment: Did you set JSLint to ES6 mode? Is there anything before that `let` statement?

Comment: there isnt anything before the let statment and i dont know anything about the ES6 mode

Comment: That sounds like the problem. You have to tell eslint/jslint what version of JavaScript you're using. `let` was added in ES6, I think it's defaulting to the older version. See https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/language-options

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you catch yourself wondering if JSLint is operating correctly, I'd suggest trying your code on [jslint.com](http://jslint.com).

This lints there:

```
let bar = document.querySelector(".bars");
let navItem = document.querySelector(".nav-items");
bar.addEventListener("click", function () {
    navItem.classList.toggle("active");
});
```

There were several things I needed to change to make your code lint, but `let` was not one of them. [More on `es6` and JSLint here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36265255/1028230).

That means, exactly as the commenters have said, that you're seeing this issue because you're not using the latest version of JSLint -- as in you're *waaaaay* behind. You're at least three years behind, it appears.

You'll need to either push your code back to es5 (`var bar = document.querySelector(".bars");`) or update your linter.